# script to number jenkins build version

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

Hi i need to write a script to number jenkins build version.

1.0.0.0
the 4th place should increase upto 19 and after that the 3rd place should be 1.
1.0.0.1, 1.0.0.2 .....1.0.0.19, 1.0.1.0,1.0.1.1....1.0.1.19

```
#!/bin/bash

file="/root/script_version/value_file.txt"
source $file
echo $abc

for ((abc=0; abc<=19; abc++))
    do
       echo $abc > $file
       echo $abc
       done

      if ["$abc" -gt 19]
        then
        xyz=$xyz+1
        echo $xyz > $file
        set abc=0
        echo $abc > file
        fi

value_file.txt

abc=0
xyz=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `$abc` and `$xyz` are supposed to be doing in your example. The following should work:

```
value_file="/root/script_version/value_file.txt"
version=$(cat $value_file)

while IFS='.' read -r version major minor patch
do
  if [[ "$patch" = "19" ]]; then
    minor=$(( minor+1 ))
    patch=0
  else
    patch=$(( patch+1 ))
  fi

  echo "${version}.${major}.${minor}.${patch}" > $value_file

done <<< "$version"
```

Read the file, split on `.` and inspect the last value. If its `19`, change back to `0` and increment the value to its left.